# as3/flex 4 accent characters

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, non-ascii-characters

I use an ArrayCollection as dataProvider in my Flexpad Button Bar:

```
<flexpad:ButtonBarBlack change="updAppStack()" id="barAppStack" selectedIndex="0" fontFamily="MyriadWebPro">
        <flexpad:dataProvider>
            <s:ArrayCollection>
                <fx:String>Attività</fx:String>
                <fx:String>Giornale</fx:String>
                <fx:String>Progetti</fx:String>
                <fx:String>Impostazioni</fx:String>
            </s:ArrayCollection>
        </flexpad:dataProvider>
```

I use MyriadWebPro as fontFamily but the "à" char is not visualized correctly, it seems to use the default font family. I also use the same font in the text fields of my objects labels, and the accent chars are visualized correctly. 
I use the

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

line at the beginning of my application.Could anyone explain me where is the difference and how can i visualize the accent chars correctly as in the fields?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Issues come from the Flexpad library: if I use Spark ButtonBar instead, the "à" character is displayed correctly.

Comment: Does that solve your problem? If so you should post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

(This answer is just a courtesy to get this off the unanswered list, since it has been a year since the apparent resolution. Asker is welcome to post and accept their own answer instead of this one.)

The described issues are coming from the Flexpad library. Using the Spark ButtonBar dispays accented characters correctly.